# Cache pre-fetching while traversing an array: what if some memory pages have being swapped out?

Tags: arrays, caching, virtual-memory, prefetch

The biggest advantage of an array, of, for example, `int`, is that, if you read it sequentially, it can be fully preloaded in cache because the CPU checks the memory access patterns and pre-fetches the next locations about to be read, so the "next" element of a vector is always in cache.

At which extent is that sentence just "theory"? Thinking about timing, for that to be true, the pre-fetcher must know how much time will take sending the next cache line to cache (which implies knowing how "slow" is the RAM), and how much time is left before such data is the next one to be read by the CPU (which implies knowing how time-consuming are the remaining instructions), so the first sequence of actions takes no longer than the second.

The specific case I have in mind: let's assume that the first 5 pages of a 10-pages-long array are in RAM and the last 5 in swap. If the next address that the pre-fetcher wants to load is the first address of the fifth page, that pre-loading time will be unpredictable long and the pre-fetcher will fail in its mission.

I know CPUs try to do a lot of guessing and speculations about the future of a process, like such cache pre-fetching, branch prediction and probably a lot of other techniques I'm not aware of, some of them probably talking to the OS to speculate together (and I'm eager to know more about this, it surprises me every time).

So, does CPUs and/or OSes try to solve that kind of guessing-timing problems, for example,  by trying to answer the pre-fetcher's question of: how much time do I need in advance for my speculative pre-fetching to cause 0 delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, does CPUs and/or OSes try to solve that kind of guessing-timing problems

No.

This is solely handled by the CPU HW. If you read some memory location the CPU will simply bring a memory block containing your location into a whole cache line.